# PHP $_SESSION Message Not Working

Tags: php

I'm  using below code for print session value. but its directly destroying session before echo step therefore the message are not showing. Please help me.

```
<?php  
    if(isset($_GET['del'])){ 
        $delete =  mysql_query("DELETE FROM favourite_tbl WHERE fid='".$_GET['del']."'");
        $_SESSION['msg']="Your Favourite Post Has Been Unlisted !";
        header('location:my-favorites.php');
    }


    if(isset($_SESSION['msg']))
    { 
        echo $_SESSION['msg']; 
        unset($_SESSION['msg']); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is destroying? You need to start the session on this page. I'd guess you never enter that conditional.

Comment: How are you setting the session?

Comment: I already started session_start(); , Its won't printing session value.

Comment: Have you used `$_SESSION["msg"] = "message";` somewhere?

Comment: The code you've presented here doesn't have `session_start()`. We work with what you present us.

Comment: You used `session_start()` on _this_ script as well as every script which uses the session? Not visible here. That is mandatory. Otherwise, enable error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script. `session_start()` must occur before any other output, as it sends a cookie header.

Comment: Did you add session_start(); function 1st?
Check your code that unset your session data

Comment: $delete =  mysql_query("DELETE FROM favourite_tbl WHERE fid='".$_GET['del']."'");
$_SESSION['msg']="Your Favourite Post Has Been Unlisted !";
header('location:my-favorites.php');

Comment: I already used session_start code at top of the page !

Comment: @Siddharth Please update your question with more code.

Comment: this question is way too unclear for too many reasons.

Comment: and that edit you just made, just made it even more unclear

Comment: I have updated my code , Kindly check it

Comment: Not related to the current question but...don't do `DELETE FROM favourite_tbl WHERE fid='".$_GET['del']` that is open to SQL injections.

Comment: all I can say here is use error reporting and check for errors on the query and add `exit;` after header. Good luck with this.

Comment: you have an answer below, ask them. That's if it's still there.

Comment: I already used it

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that way like.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['del']))
{
   $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM favourite_tbl WHERE fid='" . $_GET['del'] . "'");
   $_SESSION['msg'] = "Your Favourite Post Has Been Unlisted !";
   header('location:my-favorites.php');
   exit();
}


if (isset($_SESSION['msg']))
{
   echo $_SESSION['msg'];
   unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
?>
```

You need add to exit(); or die() function call after header redirect function. For this reason it unset your $_SESSION['msg'];